# How to run Jenkins docker container under specific user

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to run Jenkins image as jenkins2 user in following command:

```
docker run -d \
--name $cname \
--restart=always \
-v jenkins-home2:/var/jenkins_home \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 50000:50000 \
--user $(id -u jenkins2) \
--network $network \
jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Passing user id worked so far with other containers. But in Jenkins maven fails to properly get user's home directory to reach local repository (**~/.m2/** ). Instead it uses **./?/.m2/** directory.

From digging a bit I found out that java have system props set to user.name=? and user.home=?

If user is not used in run docker line then those two props are correctly set to user.name=jenkins and user.home=/var/jenkins_home

Before I start trying to manually override java proprs inside the container, I'd like to ask if there more appropriate solution to the problem?

Comment: You need to correctly configure Maven in Jenkins (global tools configuration)...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to do if there's no more elegant solution found. thank you

Comment: Dont use user in docker run , use it in Dockefile

Comment: @IjazKhan The usage of users during `docker run ..` is correct cause the user on the host system needed to be mapped into the docker container (permissions etc.) ...based on the mapped volume....

Comment: @wikisky you can create the same user with same id in dockerfile as well , you can pre-map the user in dockerfile